# MySQL Update with nested select - Syntax error

Tags: mysql

I've been playing around with the query below and just can't seem to get it to run. The select part of the query executes correctly its the update part im struggling with:

```
UPDATE n3dmx_acymailing_subscriber
SET fname=(SELECT LEFT(name, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1) 
FROM n3dmx_acymailing_subscriber) 
WHERE .....what do i put here?
```

I have tried many different variations an cannot seem to get the right one. I either get a syntax error near " on line 2 which doesn't help, or a problem with the FROM or WHERE clause. I'm still learning so any support is most welcome. I have googled but cant seem to get my head around it.
Best Regards
Donna

Comment: Why not just `UPDATE n3dmx_acymailing_subscriber set fname = LEFT(name, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1)`

Comment: Thank you so much, very simple. I got the query from another post on here, clearly i didnt need all that. Thank you again. :)

Comment: If i wanted to reverse this and get all characters after a space what would be the correct syntax? I have changed the LEFT to RIGHT and the -1 to +1 but it isnt returning the correct results, some of the words are cut off incorrectly (i.e not before the space).

Comment: Provide some example string and the expected result out of it.

Comment: Its names, basically the name column contains the first name and last name of a subscriber such as Clair Varden. Using SELECT RIGHT(name, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1) brings back 'arden'. But this does not seem to be consistant. Here are the results: omery = Montgomery
Torr - Correct
earns = Kearns
Dewar - Correct
right = Wright
jukes - Correct
nton = Shenton

Comment: So is there a chance it would contain middle name in the string as well or its always first and lastname ?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
UPDATE n3dmx_acymailing_subscriber
SET fname = LEFT(name, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1)
WHERE --your where condition
```